# 入力値の前後の空白を削除し、文字列の比較を行いたい

Tags: java, html, jsp

#### 前提

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>
<%
if (param1 == null && param2 == null) {
    param1 = ""; 
    param2 = "";
}
if (param1.equals(param2)) {
    out.println("入力値が一致しました"); 
} else {
    out.println("入力値が一致しません"); 
}
%>
</p>
<form action="stringCompare01.jsp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="param1">
<input type="text" name="param2">
<button type="submit">チェック</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

このコードを元に入力する。

```
if (param1 == null && param2 == null) {  param1 = "";   param2 = "";

}else{  param1 = param1.trim(); param2 = param2.trim();}
```

または

```
if (param1.trim().equals(param2.trim())) {out.println("入力値が一致しました"); }
```

または

```
if(param1.trim() == param2 && param2.trim() == param1){

    out.println("入力値が一致しました");
```

または

```
if(param1.trim().equals(param2) || param2.trim().equals(param1)){

    out.println("入力値が一致しました");
```

を入力試してみても一致しませんでしたと表示になってしまいます。
他にできる方法があるかご教授願います。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/c250kw4buxib10) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ①どんな入力データで確認をおこないましたか？前後に空白を含まないデータの結果は望み通りですか？